# How to fix default wrong character encoding in phpMyAdmin SQL? (Single quotes in SQL statements are generating syntax errors)

Tags: encoding, character-encoding, phpmyadmin

I am running SQL queries using phpMYAdmin and getting syntax errors when entering single-quotes by keyboard.

When I use single-quotes entered by keyboard, as opposed to using phpMyAdmin auto-generated SQL statements, I get a syntax error. (Exactly the same SQL statement that works, no problem, from the auto-generated SQL statement)

The single-quotes look different when entered by keyboard then those that are auto-generated by phpMyAdmin.

[image: Different Single Quotes causing SQL Syntax Errors]

As you can see in the image, the single-quotes for 'id', 'name' (quotes provided by phpMyAdmin's auto-generated code) are different than '3', 'Lawyers' (the type of single-quotes that show up when entered by keyboard).

Is this a bad setting on my laptop (Windows 10), or within phpMyAdmin?

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The backticks (`` ` ``) are used by MySQL to indicate database, table, and column names. Single quotes (`'`) are used to indicate a string value. So the syntax used by phpMyAdmin is correct here. The trouble you're having  with the SQL you're entering manually is because MySQL differentiates between the backtick and single quote; using the single quote for column names is incorrect here.

You can often omit the backtick entirely; it's needed specifically when the database/table/column name is also a MySQL keyword (`date`, for instance), and as you've seen can usually be left out entirely.

For further details and list of Keywords and Reserved Words in MySQL (v5.7) see [10.3 Keywords and Reserved Words](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/keywords.html) in the MySQL documentation.

Comment: Ahh..this makes sense. I wouldn't even know where to find 'backticks' on my keyboard!  If I understand correctly, the 'backticks' for database, tables, and columns are not necessary syntax for MySQL, but a convention used when phpMyAdmin auto-generates SQL statements (i.e. when I remove the 'backticks' completely for database, table and/or column), the SQL statements seem to execute correctly and I don't get any errors.

Comment: I've revised my answer to add a section addressing that, hopefully it helps further.